# JQuery ajax / PHP arrays interactions

Tags: php, html, arrays

When I load this code in my browser, there is just an alert window ('

I just want to get multiple elements from my PHP file.

main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("test.php", function(data, status){
        alert(data[0] + data[1]);
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>clic</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And test.php:

```
<?php
$data = array();
require ('steamauth/steamauth.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
$data[0] = "test00";
$data[1] = "test01";
echo $data[];
}  else {
include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
$data[0] = "test0";
$data[1] = "test1";
echo $data[];
}    
?>
```

Thank you very much
Nathan

Comment: `echo $data[];` Is incorrect (if you have error reporting enabled you'll be able to see the response error). `json_encode` then `echo`.

Comment: `echo $data[];` will also throw a `FATAL ERROR Cannot use [] for reading on line number x`

Comment: When you want to display a array, you have to write print_r() instead of echo.

Comment: @Melody print_r() is not such a good choice to transfer data between 2 languages... It's useful for a quick look while debugging.

Comment: With 'echo json_encode($data);', I still have the same error (pop up '<b')

Comment: @NathanLoisel are you parsing it on JS side via `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @Jeff yes you are right, but it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery looks fine, however if you're targeting `$("button")`, this will listen for all buttons on that page. Consider giving it an ID. For this example I updated it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("test.php", function(data){
            alert(data.foo + data.bar);
        });
    });
});
```

Inside your PHP file, you're not outputting a JSON encoding result. You need to add the content type to the `header()` and then use `json_encode()`. For this example, for maintenance, I did not use an assoc array.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
session_start(); // Your missing this unless Steamauth.php contains it

$data = array();
require ('steamauth/steamauth.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {
    $data['foo'] = "test00";
    $data['bar'] = "test01";
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
    $data['foo'] = "test0";
    $data['bar'] = "test1";
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Note, if the steamauth **does not** contain `session_start()` then `$_SESSION` will be unset.